# Mutiple Associated Domains with one iOS app

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I'm trying to implement some stuff where I need to have a multiple app site association file for a single app.

Is there a way I can configure this to leverage Universal Links.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your apple-app-site-association is a file association with a single web domain. Apple requires you access this file over https. If you own all the domains you are trying to use you can add a apple-app-site-association to each site.

You would need to configure your app to associate with each of these sites. This is done through Xcode in the Capabilities->Associated Domains tab of your project. Then add each domain as "applinks:" to your file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Brad, actually i figured out the way how to do it was some small stuff that i was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

"In your com.apple.developer.associated-domains entitlement, include a list of the domains that your app wants to handle as universal links. To do this in Xcode, open the Associated Domains section in the Capabilities tab and add an entry for each domain that your app supports, prefixed with applinks:, such as applinks:www.mywebsite.com. Limit this list to no more than about 20 to 30 domains."
- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html